# Php pdo query ORDER BY error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have one problem, I can't insert ORDER BY at this query:

```
$data = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM content '.$pages->get_limit());
```

I try to do this, but don't work, say me error:

```
$data = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY id DESC'.$pages->get_limit());
```

Comment: You have to *read* the error you get and then fix it. In your case it's list a missed space

Comment: Probably, you just forget to add **space** after **DESC**

Comment: Please, provide output of method `$pages->get_limit()`